# Is there a way to give CSS syntax highlighting to any <textarea> using any bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, content-management-system

Is there a way to give CSS syntax highlighting to any `<textarea>` using any bookmarklets or favlets? I work on a CMS where I write and manage CSS in a plain `<textarea>` like Notepad. Is there a boomarklet to enable CSS syntax highlight in specific `<textarea>` temporarily?

Should work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to write a bookmarklet, you may be able to adapt [Code Mirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about mookmarklets or Favlets, but you could write a userscript to do that.

Not sure if IE supports anything like that, but Firefox, Chrome and Opera all support userscripts. (Use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) for Firefox)

For example, I wrote [this script](http://atli.advefir.com/greasemonkey/bytes_highlight/) for myself, to highlight code on the Bytes forums, which I can use in all three browsers. (Feel free to use that if you want.)

**Edit**. It seems the [IE7pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) addon for IE supports Greasemonkey-like userscripts.

Comment: but i think ur script not for CSS

Comment: My script does not specifically highlight CSS, no. But it would not take much to add that. And you would have to edit it anyways, to get it to highlight `<textarea>` boxes rather than the `<ul>` boxes I target.

Comment: "I don't know about mookmarklets or Favlets" You will found many bookmarklets here http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/15-must-have-bookmarklets-for-web-designers-and-developers/

Comment: and here is how to make http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/

Comment: I want to do with bookmarklets only because i can't install IE7 pro.